# Reduce duplicate value

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
BasesFunctions.AllAgents = function(self){
    self.agents = self.datas.reduce(function (all, item, index) {
        item[self.valORname] == self.datas.valORname;
        all.push(item[self.valORname]);
        return all;
    }, []);
};
```

My problem is simple this function return:

```
Array [ "BLABLA", "TEST", "HONORE", "SPONGEBOB", "PATRIC", "AVEA", "TEST", "HONORE", "PATRIC", "TEST", 16 more… ]
```

I want when my value exist to not push in my array, just a different value for index 1,2,3 ... . I don't want duplicate my value like that [ "BLABLA", **"TEST"**, **"HONORE"**, "SPONGEBOB", **"PATRIC"**, "AVEA", **"TEST"**, **"HONORE"**, **"PATRIC"**, **"TEST"**, 16 more… ]

Can you help me ? plz Thanks

Thanks all i have the answer ^^ is very simple i just need to use IndexOf() like this :

```
BasesFunctions.AllAgents = function(self){
    self.agents = self.datas.reduce(function (all, item, index) {
        item[self.valORname] == self.datas.valORname;
        if(all.indexOf(item[self.valORname]) === -1)
        {
        all.push(item[self.valORname]);
        }
        return all;
    }, []);
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: what is the benefit from this line: `item[self.valORname] == self.datas.valORname;` ?!

Comment: Please check this method at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: this line is just for select my item its item.lastname because valORname = "lastname" on my js. Ok thanks for your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using filter function on Array:

```
 var arr =  [ "BLABLA", "TEST", "HONORE", "SPONGEBOB", "PATRIC", "AVEA", "TEST", "HONORE", "PATRIC", "TEST"];

var res = arr.filter((item, index, array) => array.indexOf(item) === index);

res.forEach(el => console.log(el))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the prototype of the array like:

```
// check if an element exists in array using a comparison function
// comparer : function(currentElement)
Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) { 
    for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++) { 
        if(comparer(this[i])) return true; 
    }
    return false; 
}; 

// adds an element to the array if it does not already exist using a comparer 
// function
Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) { 
    if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
        this.push(element);
    }
};
```

Now use:

```
var array = [{ name: "tom", text: "tasty" }];
var element = { name: "tom", text: "tasty" };
array.pushIfNotExist(element, function(e) { 
    return e.name === element.name && e.text === element.text; 
});
```